# How to take a screenshot during CentOS (or any Linux distro) install process?

Tags: linux, installation, centos, screenshot

I need to install a few Linux distro's on some machines and I've been asked to document the installation procedure for others to easily follow when they need to do the same.

Apart from taking pictures with a smartphone or digital camera, is there an easy way to take screenshots during the installation procedure of a Linux distro?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the installation once in a virtual machine, e.g. VirtualBox, VMWare or Hyper-V. Take screenshots with a tool running on the host system.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't think of that! I like arseniy's solution as well, but this one allows me to do it without installing software.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/installation_guide/sect-adminoptions-screenshots)

> Anaconda allows you to take screenshots during the installation process. At any time during installation, press Shift+Print Screen and anaconda will save a screenshot to /root/anaconda-screenshots.

It is valid for CentOS 7 also